# Can't insert "" character in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I check my php file and it show "Dos/Windows" and "ANSI as UTF-8".
and i already set "mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");" in my php file too. 
and the field in mysql is already "utf8_general_ci"

I can insert the chinese character "猴" but not "", what going wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

is 4 bytes (`0xF0A4A0A3`), whereas `猴` is 3 bytes (`0xE78CB4`), so to store it you need to use `utf8mb4` character set (not `utf8`).

That happens because `utf8` columns in mysql can only store up to 3 bytes per character.

References:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html
- http://www.scarfboy.com/coding/unicode-tool?s=U%2B24823
- http://www.scarfboy.com/coding/unicode-tool?s=U%2B7334

Answer (score -1):

Do you use the mysqli_real_escape_string or any other form of string sanitation like htmlspecialchars or htmlentities